# Difference between ICS and Gingerbread?

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have an app on Google Play with 20k+ downloads with 4,6+ rating, and since loads of devices got their ICS upgrades in the last few months, some(not that many) weird errors started to show up. Theese are not force closes, since I covered all possible NullPointers, etc, but for example wrong/not working networking stuffs.

First of all, here is the networking part of my app:

```
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient(); //init the HttpClient
        hc.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8"); //set the encoding to UTF-8
        HttpParams hp = hc.getParams(); //get HttpParams
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(hp, TIMEOUT); //set the timeout
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(hp, TIMEOUT); //set the timeout
        HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(hp, ActMain.userAgent); //set the user agent
        HttpResponse resp = hc.execute(new HttpGet(item.buildQuery())); //execute the query
        Stat.result=EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8); //save the result
```

This is working flawlessly on Gingerbread devices. Not a single(as far as I'm aware of) error report arrived from Gingerbread devices. But, some reports arrived from ICS devices, like, the result of the query is empty, the app will say that there is no such a result for the given options. Again, since there is no actual force close or any real report, I'm not sure if the code I gave causes the error, I'm not sure if the source of the problem is the Gingerbread vs ICS thingie, it is just a wild guess, but the only common thing I could discover from the reports was ICS.

My real question is something like this: can ICS cause the error described above? It shouldn't I think, since I use standard apache http thingies, but who knows, worth a shot.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Have you **tested** it on ICS? If not, then you need to address it for your own benefit.

Comment: If you haven't tested it on ICS, you can limit the downloading of your app to Gingerbread only in the Android Marketplace, then when you get it sorted, make it available to ICS

Comment: I did test it on ICS, and the devices I have access to, cannot reproduce this error :/ It seems like only a portion of the ICS phones produce this error. Weird..

Comment: There are a number of ICS verisons, 4.1.x, 4.2.x, 4.3.x, etc. You should try and figure out what ICS version this is happening with

Comment: Unfortunately, all the "reports" I could gather mentioned just "ICS", and I have no way to contact any of them, and since I couldn't reproduce it, thats about impossible... :/